# Possible mixing of page based and hierarchical structure in watchkit

Tags: watchkit

The Apple Watch programming guide points that you can not mix page based views and hierarchical structure, but I am not sure if my navigation scheme would fall in this mixing.

The structure I am trying to accomplish is an initial page based navigation. Then, once you tap a page, you navigate into another sub page based navigation.

The structure is shown here: 
[image: User interface structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that you're not allowed to mix page-based and hierarchical view structures in WatchKit, **unless** you present the second style modally.

So, in your case, you'd want to use a modal segue or call `presentControllerWithNames:contexts:` on `WKInterfaceController` from `1` to present `1a`, `1b`, and `1c`. You'd do the same thing from `2` to `2a`, `2b`, and `2c`.

The reason you can't use a push (hierarchical) segue from `1` to `1a` is because the page-based transition from `1` to `1a` moves from left-to-right on the screen, and so would a push segue from `1` to `2`, breaking the user's mental model about where those pages are located.

Comment: But for example Training app mix hierarchical with page based views. First you select your Training activity (Running, Walking,...) and after you have a page based for select the type of activity (Free, Time, ...).

Comment: Correct. As I mentioned, you can mix them when you present the second style modally.